# want to pass one extra column value to the $scope.seriesSelected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on Timeline charts in angularjs google chart API.
From Timeline chart API i understood that only 4 columns are allowed and the other column would be a tooltip column. 
I have a requirement where i am attaching the ID of that row along with the description and i want to pass that ID when the row is clicked but dont want to show on the label.

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope,$timeout) {
        var chart1 = {};
        chart1.type = "Timeline";
        chart1.displayed = false;
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline')
        chart1.data = {
            "cols": [{
                id: "month",
                label: "Month",
                type: "string"
            }, {
                id: "description",
                label: "Description",
                type: "string"
            }, {
                id: "start",
                label: "start",
                type: "date"
            }, {
                id: "end",
                label: "end",
                type: "date"
            }],
            "rows": [{
                c: [{
                    v: "January"
                }, {
                    v: "Jan text here -$@ 1001".trim().split(' -$@')[0]
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 3, 1)
                }, {
                    v:new Date(2018, 4, 12)
                } ]
            }, {
                c: [{
                    v: "February"
                }, {
                    v: "feb text here -$@ 1002".trim().split(' -$@')[0]
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,4, 1)
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 4, 15)
                } ]
            } , {
                c: [{
                    v: "april"
                }, {
                    v: "april text here -$@ 1003".trim().split(' -$@')[0]
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,5, 1)
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 7, 15)
                } ]
            }  ]
        };
        chart1.options = {
            timeline: {
                showRowLabels: false,
            },
        };

        $scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) {
         var rowValue = chart1.data.rows[selectedItem.row].c[1].v;
         alert(rowValue);
       }
       $scope.myChart = chart1;
   });
```

In the above js code, i am attaching the rowID like `1001,1002,..` to the description column (`Jan text here -$@ 1001".trim().split(' -$@')[0]`), but using `trim()` because i should not show the ID on the screen. When clicked on the row 
`var rowValue = chart1.data.rows[selectedItem.row].c[1].v;` i wanted to get the entire value as `Jan text here -$@ 1001` but it is not showing the ID values as shown in the demo link. Any inputs on how to pass the ID values (1001,1002..) appended in the description to the `$scope.seriesSelected` .

PS: Is it possible to include another column where i can assign the ID values(1001,1002..), but it should not be shown on the webpage/tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign properties to each cell, row, or column...

```
            c: [{
                v: "January"
            }, {
                v: "Jan text here", p: {id: 1001}
            },
            ...
```

and use data table methods to get / set...

```
dataTable.getProperty(rowIndex, columnIndex, name);

dataTable.setProperty(rowIndex, columnIndex, name, value);
```

or access the property directly from the json used as the data table...

```
chart1.data.rows[selectedItem.row].c[1].p.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I am not using dataTable. Please find my demo https://plnkr.co/edit/Xu9O26Nk4XjjqxzaMTYx?p=preview . How to pass name,value when dataTable is not used?